# How to run (create?) class in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a program that can be easily partitioned into several distinct parts. Simplified, it would look like this:

- `Reader` class would work with getting data from a certain device,
- `Analyzer` class would perform calculations on the data obtained from the device at regular intervals,
- `Form1` class that outputs UI (graphical representation of data gathered by `Reader` and number output by `Analyzer`

Naturally, I'd like those three classes to run in separate threads (on separate cores). Meaning - all methods of `Reader` run in its own thread, all methods of `Analyzer` run in its own thread, and `Form1` runs in default thread.

However, all that comes to mind is using `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker` classes, and then instead of calling some resource-heavy method on `Reader` or `Analyzer` I'd instead call

```
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

I suppose this is not the best way to do it, is it? I'd rather somehow create the class in a separate thread and leave it there for its lifespan, but I just don't get how do I do it... And I can't think of a suitable search query it seems because I haven't found answer when I searched for one.

EDIT: Thank you for the comments, I think I understand, the question itself was assuming that you can create a class "on a thread" - with implied meaning of "any method of this class called will execute on its thread" - which makes no sense, and cannot be done.

Comment: You don't "run a class in a thread". A thread runs methods. From different classes or many threads calling into 1 class.

Comment: [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a great tool for a task like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. You will need

- two threads `Reader` and `Analyzer` started by `Form1`. They basically consist of big loops that run until some flag `stopReader` or `stopAnalyzer` is set:
- two [concurrent queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), let's call them `readQueue` and `analyzedQueue`. Reader will put stuff in `readQueue`, Analyzer will read from `readQueue` and write to `analyzedQueue`, and Form1 will read from `analyzedQueue`.

  ```
  void runReader()
  {
      while (!stopReader)
      {
          var data = ...; // read data from device
          readQueue.Enqueue(data);
      } 
  }

  void runAnalyzer()
  {
      while (!stopAnalyzer)
      {
          Data data;
          if (readQueue.TryDequeue(out data))
          {
              var result = ...; // analyze data
              analyzedQueue.Enqueue(result);
          }
          else
          {
              Thread.Sleep(...); // wait a while
          } 
      }
  }
  ```
- Instead of `Thread.Sleep`, you could use a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to make Analyzer wait until a new data item is available. In that case, you might want to use a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a Boolean for `stopAnalyzer`, so that you can interrupt `BlockingCollection.Take` when stopping your algorithm.

Comment: Well, I know I can make an infinite cycle, I'd rather just have a class in a separate thread. From what I understand, that's impossible? I cannot just "have" a thread, it has to be running some method or it will exit? My device is working with callbacks btw, so I don't really call anything to read data, rather class method is called with data itself passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Istrebitel - I'd say that the approach suggested above would involve assigning the methods `runReader` and `runAnalyzer` to the reader and analyzer threads, respectively. I'm not aware of any way to make a thread _own_ a class object, ie. you cannot "have a class in a separate thread". Different methods in a class may execute on different threads. If your device works with callbacks then your reader code will execute on the thread associated with the device; eg. if callbacks come from a COM object then callbacks execute on the thread on which the COM object was created.

Comment: @Istrebitel: It's not clear what you mean by "class in a separate thread". As groverboy says, a class is just a "method and data container". Data can be accessed by *any* thread, and a method can be called by *any* thread. Obviously, you can instantiate your own classes in `runReader`.